# Unit test a service with http request only angularjs

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, service, jasmine

I have a function called getFrame in a service. The function just returns the $http call to controller.

```
angular.module('app').factory('DemoFactory', function ($http) {
    function getFrame(id) {
        var url = 'http://localhost:8080/frames/' + id + '/';
        return $http.get(url);
    }

    return {
        getFrame: getFrame
    };
});
```

Now I want to write unittest for this which I am doing as follows:

```
describe('Service: DemoFactory', function () {

    // load the service's module
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    // Instantiate service
    var $httpBackend,
        DemoFactory;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, _DemoFactory_) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        DemoFactory = _DemoFactory_;
    }));

    it('should send proper http request from getFrame', function () {
        $httpBackend.expectGET('http://localhost:8080/frames/1/').respond(200);
        DemoFactory.getFrame(1);
        $httpBackend.flush();
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });
});
```

With the given service my aim is to test whether getFrame is making a proper http request or not. So I think I am doing OK here. But something made me wonder that it block is not having any expect. So I need to confirm that for the service I have written I can have unit test as described. Do I need to have anything else in the unit test or can I do it any other way?

Comment: you use httpBackend, but you did not mock your response. read the httpBackend doc somewhere near httpBackend.when(…).response(…). and add expect to the response result.

Comment: I think I don't need to use httpBackend.when as long as I am using respond with httpBackend.expect